# can i update my jquery sortable on every page load?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i'm using jquery sortable to have an ordered list of items that can be rearranged by dragging. when the user drags and drops, the sortable function runs and updates everything, ordering it from 0-9.

However, I have the ability to insert or delete items in the list. When when a delete happens, there is a gap in the ordering (0-1-2-3-4 - 6-7-8). When adding an item, the list items are counted and 1 is added and set as the rank, inserting it at the bottom of the list. Because the ordering starts at 0, it skips a digit at the end too. (7,8,10)

But once the user drags and drops an item, the whole list is rearranged into the proper order, and everything is fine. But until then, the order is out of whack.

So I was wondering if there is a way to run the jquery sortable update without having to move an item. It would run the update but just as if you kept everything in the same spot, but it would fix my ordering problems. I would set it so that if a user just added a row or deleted a row, the function would run and the order would be set properly.

Comment: I haven't used jquery sortable so I wont put this as an answer, but I just took a look at the documentation and I think you can do what you want by calling `.sortable( "refresh" )`. [See documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to refresh the sortable each time a change is made outside the sortable list.

`.sortable( "refresh" )`

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-refresh

Comment: that's what I thought too. but it doesn't seem to be working. this is what i current have...

 `$('#test-list').sortable('refresh'); $("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order);`

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on the way you add items to the list. Looks like you're getting the items from query string?